# Laravel composer install error BroadcastServiceProvider Class not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

```
composer install --no-interaction --no-dev --prefer-dist
```

I try to deploy my app on DigitalOcean server, got error when executing above command.

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Class 'Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider' not found


Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error
```

Other details listed below:
[image]

Comment: Delete your `composer.lock` file and try again.

Comment: Same error. I also did it locally. BroadcastServiceProvider class not found

Comment: There's some cache somewhere that's causing this problem.

Comment: How do I clear that cache?